# IndexOutOfBoundsException in SpannableStringBuilder Android

Tags: android, multiautocompletetextview

I am trying to insert multiple textview with imageview in Android . That is why I have the following code :

```
public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         PhoneContactInfo phoneContactInfo = adapter.getItem(position);
         String contactname = phoneContactInfo.contactName;
        // autoCompleteTextView.setText("");
         Toast.makeText(this, " Something is clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         ClickableSpan clickSpan = new ClickableSpan() {

               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) { 
                   Log.v("clicked", view.getClass().getSimpleName());

                 //  int i = ((EditText) view).getSelectionStart();
                 //  int j = ((EditText) view).getSelectionEnd();
                //   phoneNum.getText().replace(Math.min(i, j ),
                  //         Math.max(i, j ), "", 0, "".length());

               }

           };

         TextView tv = createContactTextView(contactname);
         View view1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.contact_layout,null);
         TextView tv1 =  (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
         tv1.setText(contactname);
         view1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.bubble);
         BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) convertViewToDrawable(view1);
         bd.setBounds(0, 0, bd.getIntrinsicWidth(),bd.getIntrinsicHeight());
         contactname = contactname.substring(1, contactname.length());
        // sb.append(contactname + ","); 
         sb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bd), sb.length()-(contactname.length()), sb.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
         autoCompleteTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
         sb.setSpan(clickSpan, sb.length(),
                         sb.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
         autoCompleteTextView.setText(sb);

     }

     public TextView createContactTextView(String text){
          TextView tv = new TextView(this);
          tv.setText(text);
          tv.setTextSize(20);
          tv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.bubble);
          tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0,android.R.drawable.presence_offline, 0);
          return tv;
    }

     public static Object convertViewToDrawable(View view) {
          int spec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
          view.measure(spec, spec);
          view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
          Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(),
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
          Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
          c.translate(-view.getScrollX(), -view.getScrollY());
          view.draw(c);
          view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
          Bitmap cacheBmp = view.getDrawingCache();
          Bitmap viewBmp = cacheBmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
          view.destroyDrawingCache();
          return new BitmapDrawable(viewBmp);

        }
```

But when I have entered any text in MultiAutoCompleteTextView , it gets exception . THe logcat shows the following :

```
12-01 14:52:53.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22653): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 14:52:53.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22653): Process: com.commlink.messaging, PID: 22653
12-01 14:52:53.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22653): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (-13 ... 0) starts before 0
12-01 14:52:53.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1042)
12-01 14:52:53.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:603)
12-01 14:52:53.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:598)
12-01 14:52:53.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at com.commlink.messaging.New_Message.onItemClick(New_Message.java:84)
12-01 14:52:53.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.performCompletion(AutoCompleteTextView.java:911)
12-01 14:52:53.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.access$500(AutoCompleteTextView.java:91)
12-01 14:52:53.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView$DropDownItemClickListener.onItemClick(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1201)
12-01 14:52:53.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
12-01 14:52:53.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1152)
12-01 14:52:53.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3014)
12-01 14:52:53.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3865)
12-01 14:52:53.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
12-01 14:52:53.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
12-01 14:52:53.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
12-01 14:52:53.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5330)
12-01 14:52:53.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 14:52:53.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-01 14:52:53.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
12-01 14:52:53.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
12-01 14:52:53.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code works if I add this line : sb.append(contactname + ","); Why ? How can I solve this error ? Why does this error occurs ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to get an element from an empty array. Check whether your indexing is correct. Try debugging and see what is happening.

Comment: The code works if I add this line :  sb.append(contactname + ","); Why ?